# MySQL CASE statement returning null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two 'identical' operations

(1)

```
SELECT ticket_type_name
, amount as 'original_amount'
, CASE ticket_type_name
        WHEN ticket_type_name = 'General Admission - Friday' 
        and amount > 0 THEN amount / 400
    END AS 'NewAmount'
from analytics.deleteme
```

(2)

```
select distinct ticket_type_name, amount, amount/400 AS NewAmount
from analytics.deleteme
where amount > 0
and ticket_type_name = 'General Admission - Friday'
```

The first statement generates a value of NULL
The second statement generates a correct value of 1 (400/400)

I have added an ELSE statement at the end:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ticket_type_name
, amount as 'original_amount'
, CASE ticket_type_name
        WHEN ticket_type_name = 'General Admission - Friday'    and amount > 0   THEN amount / 400
        else amount/575
    END AS 'NewAmount'
from analytics.deleteme
where amount > 0
```

Results are the reverse of what they should be!
GA Friday should be 400/400 = 1
Everything else, eg GA Weekend should be divided by 575 (=0.82, not 1.18!)

**ticket_type_name, amount, NewAmount**
General Admission - Friday  400.0   0.69
General Admission - Weekend 475.0   1.18
General Admission - Saturday    375.0   0.93
Children (12 to 14 Years) - Weekend 100.0   0.25
Children (12 to 14 Years) - Saturday    50.0    0.125

Comment: question unclear, no sample data (or even ddl) provided.

Comment: Try `CASE WHEN ticket_type_name = 'General Admission - Friday' and amount > 0 THEN amount / 400 else amount/575 END`

Answer (score 1):

I could replicate your bug.

Just remove `ticket_type_name` after `CASE` and it works:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ticket_type_name,
  amount AS 'original_amount',
  CASE 
    WHEN 
      ticket_type_name = 'General Admission - Friday'
      AND amount > 0
    THEN 
      amount / 400
    ELSE 
      amount / 575
  END AS 'NewAmount'
FROM analytics.deleteme
WHERE amount > 0;
```

You don't need to put anything between `CASE` and `WHEN` but it's funny how this broke the query. The first comment below perfectly explains why.

As an alternative, you may move `ticket_type_name` after `CASE` and put the comparison value after `WHEN`. Like this:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ticket_type_name,
  amount AS 'original_amount',
  CASE ticket_type_name 
    WHEN 
      'General Admission - Friday'
    THEN 
      amount / 400
    ELSE 
      amount / 575
  END AS 'NewAmount'
FROM analytics.deleteme
WHERE amount > 0;
```

Long story short: either use `CASE field WHEN value…` or `CASE WHEN condition…`. You don't want to use `CASE field WHEN condition…`.

Comment: i do wonder if its a [tag:mysql] bug. given `ticket_type_name` is a possibly a `varchar` column. and `ticket_type_name = 'General Admission - Friday'` evaluates to `true`. the `varchar` will **never equal** to the boolean. hence, it will land on `else` clause. [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) definitely has 2 kind of usage syntax of `case` statement. this one is the first. [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s36NMtEdAJb2rKvPwL5KnX/0).

Comment: @BagusTesa That's surely the right explanation! I wouldn't call it a bug (this is the expected behaviour) but it's definitely confusing.